# Java Apache POI error: XMLEventFactory Provider com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxEventFactory not found

Tags: java, xml, apache, maven, apache-poi

I'm getting the run-time error:

```
javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory: Provider com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxEventFactory not found
```

using Apache POI and trying to create an XSSFWorkbook

I can create an HSSFWorkbook without any issues, but when I change my code to:

```
Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
```

It results in the run-time error. Any ideas what could be wrong? Here are my Maven dependencies I added for the Apache POI:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.15</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.15</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Why is your `ooxml-schemas` dependency 1.3, but your other dependencies 3.15? Maybe you should be using `poi-ooxml-schemas`? That has much more recent versions, as can be seen [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml-schemas).

Comment: I run successfully Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); with your dependencies. If you are using com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxEventFactory, maybe try to add the package com.ctc into you pom file? link: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ctc.wstx/woodstox-osgi

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, @Francis @yoav!  With your hints I was able to fix the error by redefining my pom.xml dependencies to the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.15</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ctc.wstx</groupId>
    <artifactId>woodstox-osgi</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

What fixed it for me was having following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.17</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- BE AWARE! It is absolutely crucial for wstx-asl to be bundled with plugin although it is present in Jira as well. -->
<!-- Jira version is not exported and it is a known bug: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-26214 -->
<!-- This artifact is supplemental for Apache POI library. -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
    <artifactId>wstx-asl</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

And running creation of XSSFWorkbook in different context:
XSSFWorkbook

```
 xssfWorkbook;
try {
    xssfWorkbook = ContextClassLoaderSwitchingUtil.runInContext(WstxEventFactory.class.getClassLoader(), (Callable<XSSFWorkbook>) XSSFWorkbook::new);
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot create XLSX workbook with WstxEventFactory class loader.");
}
```

Comment: Saved my day. Cannot use docx4j in JIRa, so Apache POI is the only option.